# bitcoin core 0.10.1 upgrade stuck syncing

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, ubuntu, error

I just upgraded from Bitcoin Core 0.9 to 0.10.1 on Ubuntu 14.4 after being gone for a few months (blockchain data is from February).  When I loaded up bitcoin-qt, it seemed to be working fine and began correctly syncing the missing blocks.  I then quit bitcoin-qt and later restarted the system and it now refuses to get blocks after February 28th, 2015.

I get the following error repeatedly:

```
ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : nonstandard transaction: non-final
```

I am now attempting a `-reindex -rescan`, but it looks like this will take a <del>day</del> week or so on my old system due to its older CPU.

Any other suggestions?

Additional notes:

- I confirmed that port 8333 was open and node was visible on bitnodes.io with multiple incoming connections.

Comment: That message is just to do with accepting transactions on the network, it won't affect your block syncing progress at all. It's not really an error, really.

Comment: Okay, good to know.  Do any of these ount as *real* errors:
 `ERROR: ConnectBlock() : inputs missing/spent`
 `ERROR: ConnectTip() : ConnectBlock 00000000000000000875efe0903a717e0b487df5d6aacceec390e341e101db94 failed`
 `ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : inputs already spent`

Comment: ConnectBlock() not passing is a major failure and would stop you syncing. It suggests you have some sort of major corruption of your state (that block is valid and does not spend already spent outputs), reindexing should resolve that but it is worrying it happened in the first place.

Comment: maybe you should post that on github issues. Even if it can theorically happen by bad luck, it is very unlikely.

Comment: This question could be improved by highlighting the "ConnectBlock error" and @Bitcoin then posting his comment as an answer instead.

Comment: **Update:** I finally gave up on the old system -- seems faster hardware is needed with newer versions of Bitcoin Core (RAM and Internet bandwidth are not enough).  Have not seen this issue again since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message `ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool` is to do with your node accepting new transactions from the network and doesn't have anything to do with your local sync state. It just means that someone made a transaction and broadcast it to you which does not respect the rules of your current software version.

It should really be "INFO" rather than error, or simply just not logged at all.

Answer (score -3):

Try Do `invalidateblock` then `reconsiderblock` .

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are suggesting? These are not command-line options for [bitcoin core](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin).